# disable textbox input history in order to display keyword suggestion

Tags: php

I have a textbox, where I input a word, it will provide a list of suggestion based on that word (just like keyword suggestion of google search), but the list of suggestion now is hidden under the textbox history. How should I disable the textbox history?

Comment: use `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 0):

To Disable Auto Complete Use:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

But Disabling it will be a problem for you too! where do you want to show your own suggestions?

Check [this link](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/javascript/suggest1.html), it's a full demonstration for your purpose.

It's not exactly brief, but quick reading is possible.

Hope It Helps.